# PHP: How to use two dimensional array to display menu?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I think I'm picking this up pretty well, but I'm just stuck on this. I want to display this menu using an array and foreach loop:

```
<a href="/design/payments"><img src="/img/page-icons/credit-card21.png" />Payments</a>
<a target="_blank" href="/cloud"><img src="/img/page-icons/upload123.png" />Cloud</a>
<a target="_blank" href="/portal"><img src="/img/page-icons/earth208.png" />Portal</a>
```

So to do that I need to turn that into this line in PHP:

```
echo '<a href="' . $link . '" target="' . $target . '"><img src="/img/page-icons/' . $image . '" />' . $title . '</a>';
```

To fill that out in the loop we need to create something like this... which is where I'm stuck:

```
foreach( $stamp as $link => $target ){
    echo '<a href="/' . $link . '" target="' . $target . '">';

    foreach( $stamp[] as $title => $image ){
        echo '<img src="/img/page-icons/' . $image . '" />' . $title;
    }

    echo '</a>';
}
```

I don't really know how to go about the above, just been messing around with it for a while today. I also don't want to always display `target="' . $target . '"` on every link.

The array would probably be a two dimensional array? Something like this any way:

```
$stamp = array(
    'link' => array('title' => 'image'),
    'link' => array('title' => 'image'),
    'link' => array('title' => 'image')
);
```

---

EDIT:

There's some confusion of what 'target' is, I want to echo 4 values from an array into a link, target is one of the values. I didn't know how to use that in the array so I just left it out.

Comment: waht is target here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
foreach( $stamp as $link => $target )
```

The `$link` variable contains the string "*link*" and the `$target` variable is an array such as `['title' => 'image']`.

What you should probably do is have an array like this:

```
// Init links
$links = array();

// Add links
$links[] = array(
   'title' => 'My Title',
   'href' => 'http://www.google.com',
   'target' => '_blank',
   'image' => 'image.png',
);

foreach ($links as $link)
{
   echo '<a href="'.$link['href'].'" target="'.$link['target'].'">';
       echo '<img src="/img/page-icons/' . $link['image'] . '" />';
       echo $link['title']; 
   echo '</a>';
}
```

This is a bit more flexible approach that lets you add other data items to the structure in the future. That `$links` array could easily be generated in a loop if you have a different data source such as a database as well.

---

**EDIT**

To answer your further question, you can prefix the link building with a set of sane defaults like this:

```
foreach ($links as $link)
{
   // Use the ternary operator to specify a default if empty
   $href = empty($link['href']) ? '#' : $link['href'];
   $target = empty($link['target']) ? '_self' : $link['target'];
   $image = empty($link['image']) ? 'no-icon.png' : $link['image'];
   $title = empty($link['title']) ? 'Untitled' : $link['title'];

   // Write link
   echo "<a href='$href' target='$target'>";
       echo "<img src='/img/page-icons/$image' />";
       echo $title; 
   echo "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now with what you've provided, how would I see if target exists in the array and if it does then echo target if not then echo the link without the `target=""`? In my mind I see it being done through an if statement like `if (array_key_exists('target', $links)) {}`?

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional help. If my answer has helped you, can you please accept it?

Comment: Is there a way to check if target is actually in the array though?

Answer (score 0):

you can set your array like:

```
$stamp = array(
 '0' => array('title'=>$title 'image'=>$image,'link'=>$link,'target'=>$target),
 '1' => array('title'=>$title, 'image'=>$image,'link'=>$link,,'target'=>$target),
 '2' => array('title'=>$title 'image'=>$image,'link'=>$link,'target'=>$target)
);
```

and in foreach you can write

```
$i=0;
foreach( $stamp as $st=> $target ){
echo '<a href="/' . $st['link'] . '" target="' . $st['target'] . '">';


    echo '<img src="/img/page-icons/' . $st['image'] . '" />' . $st['title'];


echo '</a>';
```

}